# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (viPhoneme library)

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, oserror

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\IR Research\complete_phonetics.py", line 269, in <module>
    phoneme_trans.append(vi2IPA(lines))
  File "C:\Users\brije\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\viphoneme\__init__.py", line 578, in vi2IPA
    TN= TTSnorm(text)
  File "C:\Users\brije\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vinorm\__init__.py", line 25, in TTSnorm
    subprocess.check_call(Command, env=myenv, cwd=A)
  File "C:\Users\brije\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\brije\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 345, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\brije\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\brije\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I am trying to run and it shows the above error on vi2IPA(lines). I am using the [**viphoneme**](https://pypi.org/project/viphoneme/) library to convert a text document to its corresponding phonemes. Also, I am using an i5, 9th gen 64-bit Win10 OS. There are other solutions to the same type of issue but I find them quite irrelevant.

Comment: `vinorm` uses an ELF executable -> it only works on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for help! Also, one can refer to this: https://github.com/v-nhandt21/Viphoneme/issues/3